# Fit a polynomial glmer (lme4) model

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

having only dim memories of this subject from uni, I'm struggling a bit with fitting a polynomial binomial mixed effects model with two nested random effects.

My data are counts of success and failures (s and f) at a variety of values of x.  There are two random effects, r1 and a nested random effect r2.

I would like to try fitting a polynomial model, up to ninth order and use the AIC values to find the minimum adequate model, but I'm unsure of the syntax.

So I've got three questions really:

Is the code below currently correct?

What is the syntax to fit a glmer polynomial?

Is this whole thing statistical nonsense, and should i try a different approach?

Thanks for your help, code below:

```
require(lme4)

## SAMPLE SET:
## x fixed effect
## s count success
## f count fail
## r1 random effect 1
## r2 random effect 2

sample.set <- data.frame(x = runif(1000,-100,100),
                         s = round(runif(1000,100,1000),0),
                         f = round(runif(1000,100,10000),0),
                         r1 = c(rep("A",250), rep("B",250), rep("C",250), rep("D",250)))

sample.set$r2 <- sapply(sample.set$r1,function(x){if(x == "A")                {as.character(round(runif(1,1,5), 0 ))} else
                                                  if(x == "B") {as.character(round(runif(1,6,10), 0))} else
                                                  if(x == "C") {as.character(round(runif(1,11,15),0))} else
                                                               {as.character(round(runif(1,16,20),0))}})

prop.tab <- cbind(sample.set$s,sample.set$f)

mm.model <- glmer(prop.tab ~ sample.set$x + (sample.set$x | sample.set$r1) + (sample.set$x | sample.set$r2),
                  family = binomial, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 0)
```

Comment: If you need statistical advice and model recommendations, you should post at [stats.se] instead. As written, this does not appear to be a specific programming question and as such is off topic for Stack Overflow.